# How to view the progress of the django app in the browser

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want the process of the app to be dispayed in the browser so that suers know how much it has been done.

However, in django, the view receives the event that occurred in the template(browser) and passes it back to the template, so I don't know how to pass it from the view itself to the template.

For example, when the user clicks a button, a total of 3 fuctions are executed in trun. At this time, I want to show 'End of function1, start of function 2' when fuction 1 ends. it same way for fuction2,3.

I'm not sure if I should do this in view or make it in JS. The functions runs in python.
I'm not familiar with django, so this might be a very rudimentary question. Please Help me :)

The fuctions are performed in the view in order, and when each function is completed, render or redirect is perfomed to template. but it is expressed only at the first fuction and does not proceed any further.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/logging/). I don't think there is a solution to your usecase, since almost no website online displays what functions ran in the background. You would have to "invent" that on your own. But check out logging! That is the default way to inform yourself about the status of your app

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data from the views in the template by passing the data into a dictionary in views.
For e.g. if I want to pass the value of lets say p = 5 from views to template I can do it while returning as

```
return render(request, 'template_name', {'p' : 5})
```

Comment: Thanks reply. but it is not the answer i wanted.

#view

def step1(a):
    return a

def progress(request):

    a = step1('1')
    print('1')
    return render(request, 'progressbar/index.html', {'a': a})
    
    a = step1('2')
    print('2')
    return render(request, 'progressbar/index.html', {'a': a})
    
    a = step1('3')
    print('3')
    return render(request, 'progressbar/index.html', {'a': a})

In this case, 1,2,3 are not all visible, but only 1 is visible in the template.